# spring security url pattern not working for sub-paths

Tags: spring-security

I want spring security to intercept

```
/admin
/admin/
/admin/products
```

I am using

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

but only the first url `/admin` is intercepted and is redirected to the login page.

here is my config xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin"
        authentication-failure-url="/login" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="auser" password="123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Try with `<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated"/>` and `<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-authentication-error-url="/login" session-fixation-protection="newSession"/>`

Comment: Also set `<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access